# const TypedeffedIntPointer not equal to const int *

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code:

```
typedef int* IntPtr;
const int* cip = new int;
const IntPtr ctip4 = cip;
```

I compile this with Visual Studio 2008 and get the following error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'const IntPtr'

Clearly my understanding of typedefs is not what is should be.

The reason I'm asking, I'm storing a pointer type in a STL map. I have a function that returns a const pointer which I would like to use to search in the map (using map::find(const key_type&). Since

```
const MyType*
```

and

```
const map<MyType*, somedata>::key_type
```

is incompatible, I'm having problems.

Regards
Dirk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `const IntPtr ctip4`, you are declaring a *const-pointer-to-int*, whereas `const int * cip` declares a *pointer-to-const-int*. These are not the same, hence the conversion is impossible.

You need to change the declaration/initialization of cip to

```
int * const cip = new int;
```

To resolve this issue in your example, you need to either change the key type of the map to `const MyType *` (whether or not it makes sense depends on your application, but I think that changing a MyType object via a pointer used as key in the map is unlikely), or fall back to const_casting the parameter to find:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    const int * cpi = some_func();

    std::map<const int *, int> const_int_ptr_map;
    const_int_ptr_map.find(cpi); //ok

    std::map<int *, int> int_ptr_map;
    int_ptr_map.find(const_cast<int *>(cpi)); //ok
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`const IntPtr` is the same as `int* const`, not `const int*`.

That is, it is a `const` pointer to an `int`, not a pointer to a `const int`.

A solution would be to provide two typedefs:

```
typedef int* IntPtr;
typedef const int* ConstIntPtr;
```

and use `ConstIntPtr` when you need a pointer to a `const int`.